# Why is a Kotlin enum property not a compile time constant?

Tags: kotlin, enums

The primary target of this question is understanding the implementation and why it is like this. A solution or workaround for it would of course also be highly appreciated...

**Given this example:**

```kotlin
enum class SomeEnum(val customProp: String) {
  FOO("fooProp"),
  BAR("barProp");
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class TheAnnotation(
  val targetValue: String
)

@TheAnnotation(targetValue = SomeEnum.FOO.customProp)
fun testFun() {
  
}
```

**The compilation results in the following error:**

> SomeEnum.kt: (14, 30): An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

For obvious reasons, annotation values (along with others) must be compile-time constants, which makes sense in many different ways. What is unclear to me, is why `customProp` is not treated as a constant by the compiler.

If enums are defined as finite, closed sets of information, they should, in my understanding, only be mutable at compile-time a.k.a. "compile-time constant". For the unlikely case that enums somehow are modifiable at runtime in Kotlin, that would answer the question as well.

**Addendum:**

The enum value (e.g. `SomeEnum.FOO`) is actually treated as a compile-time constant. The proof is, that the following slightly changed snippet compiles:

```kotlin
enum class SomeEnum(val customProp: String) {
  FOO("fooProp"),
  BAR("barProp");
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class TheAnnotation(
  val targetValue: SomeEnum
)

@TheAnnotation(targetValue = SomeEnum.FOO)
fun testFun() {

}
```

Comment: Reasonable doubt maybe `Foo(if System.currentTimeMillis() % 2L == 0L) "hello" else "bye")`. I havent tried it because Im on my phone now, but if that compiles then you have your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> enums are defined as finite, closed sets of information, they should, in my understanding, only be mutable at compile-time

Actually, no. An enum class is just a special kind of class, that doesn't allow you to create any new instances other than the ones that you name in the declaration, plus a bunch more syntactic sugars. Therefore, like a regular class, it can have properties whose values are only known at runtime, and properties that are mutable (though this is usually a very bad idea).

For example:

```
enum class Foo {
    A, B;

    val foo = System.currentTimeMillis() // you can't know this at compile time!
}
```

This basically de-sugars into:

```
class Foo private constructor(){
    val foo = System.currentTimeMillis()
    companion object {
        val A = Foo()
        val B = Foo()
    }
}
```

(The actual generated code has a bit more things than this, but this is enough to illustrate my point)

`A` and `B` are just two (and the *only* two) instances of `Foo`. It should be obvious that `Foo.A` is not a compile time constant<sup>*</sup>, let alone `Foo.A.foo`. You could add an `init` block in `Foo` to run arbitrary code. You could even make `foo` a `var`, allowing you to do hideous things such as:

```
Foo.A.foo = 1
// now every other code that uses Foo.A.foo will see "1" as its value
```

You might also wonder why they didn't implement a more restricted enum that doesn't allow you to do these things, and *is* a compile time constant, but [that is a different question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819).

See also: [The language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#enum-class-declaration)

---

<sup>*</sup> Though you can still pass `Foo.A` to an annotation. To an annotation, `Foo.A` is a compile time constant, because all the annotation has to do, is to store the name "Foo.A", not the object that it refers to, which has to be computed at runtime.

Comment: Good point, while your statement "It should be obvious that Foo.A is not a compile time constant" is actually wrong. `Foo.A` is a compile-time constant, as every enum is, but the property `Foo.A.foo` isn't, because,  and there you are right, it is / could be mutable.

Comment: @frank_neff Objects can't be compile-time constants, because they are constructed at runtime, using constructors that could have any arbitrary logic inside. The compiler can only know there is the `Foo.A` object, but it can't know what it is exactly. So this is more like a singleton than constant.

Comment: `Foo.A` isn't a compile time constant either. See [this section](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#exhaustive-when-expressions) of the spec. It's a special case that it can be used as an annotation parameter.

Comment: @frank_neff Suppose `Foo.A` were a constant expression, then it follows that `"${Foo.A}"` is a constant expression according to the rules I linked above. This means that we could pass `"${Foo.A}"` to an annotation that takes a string. However, this is not possible.

Comment: @Sweeper You're totally right with the string interpolation example and I didn't know that the Kotlin compiler tests if a string interpolation only consists of constants or not, and if so, also flags it as constant, which I btw. find very impressive.
Anyways, I can't see an explicit link between annotation parameters and "exhaustive when" in the language spec. Also, the compiler error "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant" is incomplete/wrong for that case and should probably be improved.
Thanks for your explanations

Comment: @frank_neff it’s not about the exhaustive when. Constant expressions just so happened to be specified in that section. But you do have a point here - we have been talking about two kinds of constant expressions. Broot and I were both referring to the kind specified in the exhaustive when section of the spec, but you seem to be more interested in the expressions that can be passed to annotations, which are also called “compile time constants” by the compiler, making this confusing.